# Catch both links and ips with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hyperlink, timeout, try-catch

with the help of forum, I made a script that catch all link of the topics of this page https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/ . These topics contains a list of proxies. The script is this:

```
import urllib.request, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), "lxml")

base = "https://www.inforge.net/xi/"

for tag in soup.find_all("a", {"class":"PreviewTooltip"}):
    links = tag.get("href")
    final = [base + links]

final2 = urllib.request.urlopen(final)

for line in final2:
    ip = re.findall("(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3}):(?:[\d]{1,5})", line)
    ip = ip[3:-1]

for addr in ip:
    print(addr)
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proxygen5.0.py", line 13, in <module>
    sourcecode = urllib.request.urlopen(final)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 456, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

I know that the problem is in the part of: `final2 = urllib.request.urlopen(final)` but i don't know how to solve

What can I do to print ips?

Comment: The problem is that `final = [base + links]` create a list with one element, and than you use the list for `final2 = urllib.request.urlopen(final)`, where you should pass a string (the url) not a list.

Comment: yeah.. i'm stupid, you'r right.. so how can I bypass this? if you are available to answer

Comment: Replace `final = [base + links]` with `final = base + links`. Note that you're keeping only the last _final_ you parse from the tags, if you need all of them you should change other code.

Comment: i'm  a newbie and i'm keeping on trying but i still not realized what i should i change in "the other code" as you said first. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you want, it's commented so you can understand all the passages:

```
import urllib.request, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), "lxml")

base = "https://www.inforge.net/xi/"

# Iterate over all the <a> tags
for tag in soup.find_all("a", {"class":"PreviewTooltip"}):
    # Get the link form the tag
    link = tag.get("href")
    # Compose the new link
    final = base + link

    print('Request to {}'.format(final))    # To know what we are doing
    # Download the 'final' link content
    result = urllib.request.urlopen(final)

    # For every line in the downloaded content
    for line in result:
        # Find one or more IP(s), here we need to convert lines to string because `bytes` objects are given
        ip = re.findall("(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3}):(?:[\d]{1,5})", str(line))
        # If one ore more IP(s) are found
        if ip:
            # Print them on separate line
            print('\n'.join(ip))
```

Comment: you are an angel! you helped a newbie like me. i don't know how can I thanks you... you are the best

Comment: last question and then i've done.. if I would save all the caught ips in a file, how could I do? I've tried with: out_file = `open("proxy.txt","w") out_file.write(ip) out_file.close()` but it saves just an ip.

Comment: You need to open the file in `append` mode, or all the content is overwritten, to do so, use `"a"`, instead of `"w"` when opening the file.

Comment: If you want to learn, my advice is to take a look at this **free** book http://www.diveintopython3.net/ ;)

Comment: Thanks again. Anyway I red all a guide on html.it, but i'm still a bit stuck.. but I'm learning! :D